# Is 'Another Europe is possible' correct English?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, phrase-usage

Given that we don't have a second Europe, I thought it should be something like 'A different Europe is possible'. Or does this sentence have the same meaning?

Comment: What's the context? What's the intended meaning? What do you consider "*correct English*" to be? Note that "colourless green ideas sleep furiously" is "*correct English*" but is also nonsensical.

Comment: We have, in metaphorical terms, infinite Europes.

Answer (score 1):

they have different meanings. 
Here are some things to remember about another: 1) It has two primary meanings - It can mean "one more", as in "I'll have another beer." = "I'll have one more beer." It could also mean "some other", in which case it's meaning and usage becomes similar to different: "I would like to try on another (some other) dress." is fairly similar to "I would like to try on a different dress (not this one)."
2) Unlike the word "different", "another" is ALWAYS SINGULAR. The plural form of another is other. You cannot say another people, you have to say other people :)

Here are some things to remember about different: It basically means "distinct" eg. "Give me a different example." (which means that you do not want to hear the same example). If you say "Give me another example" it means "Give me one more example" or "Give me some other example."
[reference](http://www.infosquares.com/eslblog/blog_03252008.html)

Comment: Yes, it is correct English. @Zaki gives the example "I would like to try on another (= a different) dress." In the same way you can speak of "Another (= a different version of) Europe".

Comment: Thanks! You've been very helpful.